# Flutter web stuck on hot restart after upgrading to 2.5.2

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

It gets stuck only if a hot reload was after some change in the code. If no change hot reload work fine.
The issue occurs with any project, even on a new default flutter project and only with flutter web. It works fine on android and iOS.

Previous flutter version is 2.2.3

I have already tried:

- change channels,
- disable win defender,
- run on chrome dev,
- run on Edge,
- reinstall everything including Windows and reset drivers,
- vs code,
- intellij idea,
- run without debug,
- all that i could find in other similar topics.

FLUTTER DOCTOR:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.194], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (11 days ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Dev\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2
    • Flutter plugin version 61.2.4
    • Dart plugin version 212.5486

[√] VS Code (version 1.61.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\FoT-P\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 94.0.992.38
```

MSINFO:

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/6XwNWrlN5wuC7g

PS: Now I am using windows 11 but the issue is present on Windows 10 too

EXAMPLE:

1. Create new flutter project
2. Change the Text widget arg to 'You have pushed the button this many times 123:'
3. Get a very slow or stuck hot reload

[IDE Screen with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRyPl.png)